# OpenGL Memory Leaks while using glClearColor or glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix pair?

Tags: memory, opengl, memory-leaks, glew

I started creating a small game engine for an independent project.  When writing the graphics portion of the engine, I noticed there was a memory leak that dissapears when I stop using glClearColor and the glPushMatrix/glPopMatrix pairs.
From what I've researched it appears to be a common occurrence, but I haven't found an answer as to why this occurs.

The bizarre thing is, the leak goes on for a minute or two, and then just stops (very consistently).
Using the task manager, it shows 11,012K when the leak stops.

Additional Notes: I am not using GLUT, but I am using GLEW_1.7 for mapped vbo's.

Any ideas what could be causing this?
Is is just a non-issue because of something odd that OpenGL does under the hood?

These are the only place I'm calling glClearColor, glPushMatrix, and glPopMatrix.

```
void GraphicsDevice::updateCameraAndClear(IWindow* window)
{
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    gluPerspective(32, window->getAspectRatio(), 0.0, 100.0);

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();

    glClearColor(100.0f / 255, 149.0f / 255, 237.0f / 255, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE); // Enable Culling
    glCullFace(GL_BACK);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_POLYGON_SMOOTH);
}

void Engine::draw(void)
{
    GraphicsDevice::Instance()->updateCameraAndClear(_window);
    if ( !_states.empty() )
    {
        for(std::vector<IState*>::iterator i = _states.begin(); i != _states.end(); i++)
        {
            glPushMatrix();
            (*i)->draw(this);
            glPopMatrix();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you detect memory leak? The number you see in task manager is a working set size, which, I believe, never decreases for a single process. BTW, `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` functions are deprecated for quite some time already.

Comment: I was using the windows task manager to view how much the program was using. I wasn't aware that these were deprecated, but I still need to use them since I'm only using OpenGL 1.4 - 2.0. Although the hardware I'm using supports 4.2, I want the game to be available to those on older machines.

Comment: If it was really a leak in a functions that are called dozens of time per second, the number in task manager would steadily grow without stopping.

Comment: Aren't glFrustum is a part of gluPerspective itself?

Comment: Oops, yes it is. I'll remove that line.

Comment: Have you tried running this on different vendor cards?  It could possibly be a driver issue.

Comment: Not yet, I'll have to try that in a bit.

Comment: All a function being deprecated means (for OpenGL) is that it will not part part of some future version. In the case of `glPushMatrix`/`glPopMatrix` this was version 3.1. Thus, it is still OK to use them if your program uses OpenGL 3.0 or earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you use the Push/Pop pair wrongly, pushing one extra time more than required. But eventually that would lead to buffer overflow..

Check your Push/Pop pairs and make sure thay are pairs indeed. The leak could be in surrounding code as well.

**EDIT:** OpenGL receives instructions, but they are not executed immediately. OpenGL has a plan of its own. If you `glDeleteTextures` you are not guaranteed the texture will be removed until `glFinish`/`glFlush` command (or even after?). Maybe there's something else accumulating in your `Draw` code that OpenGL keeps in memory. Which gives described effect when co-joined with glPush/glPop pairs.

Comment: I've double checked and I'm only calling a single pair like so,
<code>
void Engine::draw(void)
{
 GraphicsDevice::Instance()->updateCameraAndClear(_window);

 if ( !_states.empty() )
 {
  for(std::vector<IState*>::iterator i = _states.begin(); i != _states.end(); i++)
  {
   glPushMatrix();
   (*i)->draw(this);
   glPopMatrix();
  }
 }
}
</code>

Comment: _"Perhaps you use the Push/Pop pair wrongly, pushing one extra time more than required. But eventually that would lead to buffer overflow"_ -- OpenGL will report stack overflow with a dedicated error message (`GL_STACK_OVERFLOW`, 0x0503). If that is not what `glGetError` returns, then it's not what has happened. Stacks are typically not very deep (less than 32), so this is something that would happen very quickly.

Comment: I just checked to make sure and printed glGetError every frame and it's returning GL_NO_ERROR each time.

Comment: Since you have accepted my answer, please let everyone know where was the bug after all. This could help others with similar problems.